# Java ASM finding concrete implementing class

Tags: java, bytecode

I'm new to java byte coding and I have been struggling with this problem for a while.
I'm using java ASM bytecode engineering library. I would like to find all methods and 
classes where those methods are implemented that a particular method calls. Name and 
description of the called method and name of the class that implements called method.
The problem is that when a method that is being analyzed calls method that is defined
in an interface or abstract class I cant find the name of the concrete class that
actually implements the called method. Here is also some of my code and test output that
visualizes situation.

```
public class MyClassVisitor extends ClassVisitor {    
       public List<MethodCallers> methodCallers;

       public MyClassVisitor() {
           super(Opcodes.ASM4);
           this.methodCallers = new ArrayList<>();
       }

       @Override
       public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc, String        signature, String[] exceptions) {
            MethodCallers methodData = new MethodCallers(name, desc);
            this.methodCallers.add(methodData);
            return new MyMethodVisitor(methodData);
        }
}

 public class MyMethodVisitor extends MethodVisitor {
        private final MethodCallers methodCallers;

    public MyMethodVisitor(MethodCallers methodCallers) {
        super(Opcodes.ASM4);
        this.methodCallers = methodCallers;
    }

    @Override
    public void visitMethodInsn(int opcode, String owner, String name, String desc) {
        String implementingClass = owner;

        if(opcode == Opcodes.INVOKEINTERFACE) {
            /* Here I would need to find the concrete implementing class */
            /* implementingClass = something */
        }

        this.methodCallers.addCaller(new CalledMethod(name, desc, implementingClass));
    }
 }

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClassReader classReader = new ClassReader("TestClass");
        MyClassVisitor classVisitor = new MyClassVisitor();

        classReader.accept(classVisitor, 0);
        //...
}
```

and the output:

Name:  Description: ()V
Called these methods
 called name:  Desc:  in class java/lang/Object
 called name:  Desc:  in class java/util/ArrayList

Name: increment Description: (I)V

Called these methods
 called name: valueOf Desc: valueOf in class java/lang/Integer

called name: add Desc: add in class java/util/List /* Here I would like to see ArrayList    instead of List */

All help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you want to do this statically or at runtime?

Comment: Sorry I'm not exactly sure what you mean but none of the classes that program analyses change during analyzation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the concrete class you need to look at the `extends class` or `implements interfaces`
When you find these classes in the header, you need to look up those classes in turn and possibly their parents as well.

Comment: But how would I know which one of those classes that implement the interface is actually the one the method called?

Comment: @user3841112 You search through them recursively until you find it.

Comment: But how will I recognize it? visitMethodIns only gives me opcode, owner, name and  desc. And owner is the name of the interface, name and desc of the called method are same in all the classes that implement that interface So what can I use to recognize the right class from all the implementing classes?

Comment: @user3841112 What do you mean by the "right class"?  As you say, there could be multiple classes which implement a method.  If you are looking for a specific implementation you need to say what that is.

Comment: By the the right class I mean the class which has the specific implementation of the method that the method being analyzed called. For example in my test output I would find many classes that implement List interface ArrayList, AttributeList, LinkedList ... How would I know that the method being analyzed called ArrayLists implementation of the method? The implementation which I am looking for is the implementation that the method being analyzed called. I have no other knowledge of that class than what the MethodVisitors visitMethodIns gives me.

Comment: @user3841112 If you have a List in the code, the implementation called depends on the List passed/used at runtime. i.e. there is no way to statically determine that a List implementation, perhaps you don't even have the code for, could be called in the future.  It's like saying I have an object passed in, how do I know which type a developer will pass in when they use it?

Comment: Maybe you are right and it's not possible to figure out which concrete class was actually called. Although I found another question with a possible solution. I can't fully understand it at least yet. I think that in this question had a similar problem [possible solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10744748/asm-transformation-to-find-concrete-class-type). There might be a possible solution. Thank you for your help Lawrey.

Comment: It is possible to determine all the classes you create in a body of code, possible all those which are passed to a method, but this doesn't consider that this might be more than you need. e.g. `List l = flag ? new ArrayList() : new LinkedList();`  The best solution is to write code which doesn't need to know the concrete type.

Comment: Thank you for clearing this thing out for me. I will edit your answer so that if someone has the same problem he or she can find the answer in these comments.